# Page redirect issue in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have following rule sin my `.htaccess` file.

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^search/$ /search.php [QSA]

    RewriteRule ^page/([^.]+)/$ /$1? [L,R=301]  

    RewriteRule ^place/france/$ /search/?country=1&hcp=1 [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^place/canary-islands/$ /search/?country=6&hcp=1 [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^place/italy/$ /search/?country=2&hcp=1 [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^place/portugal/$ /search/?country=5&hcp=1 [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^place/spain/$ /search/?country=4&hcp=1 [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^place/united-kingdom/$ /search/?country=3&hcp=1 [QSA]

    RewriteRule ^place/([^.]+)/([^.]+)/$ /page.php?t=$1-$2&ltwo=yes [QSA]

    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ /page.php?t=$1 [QSA]
</ifModule>
```

Following pages runs ok:

```
www.mywebsite.com/search/
www.mywebsite.com/some-page-url/
```

But this page doesn't run properly and redirects always to page.php page.

```
www.mywebsite.com/place/france/
```

How can I fix this please advise?

Comment: check for `L` and `NS` tags

Comment: @imsiso removing those rules is not solution, I need those rules to run as well.

Comment: @regilero you suggestion of adding `L` worked. I did the rule like this `RewriteRule ^place/france/$ /search/?country=1&hcp=1 [L,QSA]` and those are working. If you could add your comment as answer then I can mark it as answer then. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to add the `[L]` or `[last]` (I'm tired of the cryptic short form) tag in the RewriteRules, so that a matching rule will stop the process.

If the last Rule is a catch-all it should also contain the `[NS]` or `[nosubreq]` tag to prevent internal redirections checks match. As even with a `[last]` tag the result is not an external redirect but an internal redirect, and this means the resulting url is checked one more time on all the rules (here the `/search/...` url).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your current conf does for `www.mywebsite.com/place/france/`

1) place/france/ gets rewritten to search/?country=1&hcp=1 (correct). the rewrite process continues to the next rule.

2) Now we have `search/` which gets captured by the last rule and gets rewritten to `page.php`

There may be a couple of ways to do this (e.g. using L flags) but my suggestion is to move the `search` rule downwards and before the last rule, so the url will get properly rewritten to search.php, before the last rule comes in.

Like this:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>    
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^page/([^.]+)/$ /$1? [L,R=301]  

  RewriteRule ^place/france/$ /search/?country=1&hcp=1 [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^place/canary-islands/$ /search/?country=6&hcp=1 [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^place/italy/$ /search/?country=2&hcp=1 [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^place/portugal/$ /search/?country=5&hcp=1 [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^place/spain/$ /search/?country=4&hcp=1 [QSA]
  RewriteRule ^place/united-kingdom/$ /search/?country=3&hcp=1 [QSA]

  RewriteRule ^place/([^.]+)/([^.]+)/$ /page.php?t=$1-$2&ltwo=yes [QSA]

  RewriteRule ^search/$ /search.php [QSA]

  RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/$ /page.php?t=$1 [QSA]
</ifModule>
```